# Change the source of a dimension in one go?

Tags: ssas

This is one of those "where the **** did Visual Studio put the button to do that?  You ***must*** be able to..." questions.

A dimension in an SSAS project runs off a table in the DSV.  Now I've created a named query (which just excludes certain unwanted rows from the table).  How do I switch the dimension over to point to this named query?  Nothing's changed in the set of columns.

What I did was to go to every attribute, and change the Source of its KeyColumn (and NameColumn, where appropriate) to the named query - which involved reselecting the same column name.

There just **has** to be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the end.

You don't do this in the dimension itself, which takes the "friendly name" of the object overlaid on the real datasource in the DSV as its source.

Instead, you "point" that friendly name to a different database object (table, view) in the DSV itself: right-click the object and select "Replace Table".

Note that the "friendly name" won't change, so that it will look as if nothing has happened, until you see that the Name property has changed to point to the object you just chose.   (I usually change the friendly name to give at least some information about the underlying database object).